# Asked for Terminus, and got TeX Gyre Chorus instead

Tags: debian, fonts, fontconfig

For a long time I've dreamed of an "all-[Terminus](http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net/img/12x24b.gif)" desktop, but couldn't figure out how to do it.  My taste in fonts is so far outside of the mainstream<sup>1</sup> that I could not find any even remotely helpful information.

I finally stumbled on the right incantation.  I just had to install the following `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` file

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
  <match>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="strong">
      <string>Terminus</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Basically, the single `<match></match>` clause in this config should "map" every font to Terminus.  Now I get Terminus pretty much everywhere:

### [image]

I was pretty happy with the results, but the gods clearly viewed my exploit as hubris.  They decided it to punish it by having VirtualBox switch most of its text to [TeX Gyre Chorus](http://luc.devroye.org/TexGyreChorus-2008.png).  (At least the gods have a sense of humor.)

[image]

Is there something I can add to my `fonts.config` that will force VirtualBox to use Terminus (or at least revert to its original font)?  (Of course, it goes without saying that any solution must not undo the use of Terminus everywhere else.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> E.g., I *much* prefer a crisp (i.e. non-antialiased, non-scaled) bitmapped font to an anti-aliased scaled one.  By all the evidence I've seen, this preference is exactly the opposite to everyone else's.  And yes, some new ultra-high-resolution displays can make anti-aliased scaled fonts look almost as crisp as a bitmapped font on a lower resolution display, but on Linux "ultra-high-resolution" equals "microscopic text".  Until Linux offers good scaling support for ultra-high-resolution displays, this is not an option for me.</sup>